# Angular-JS: ng-repeat multiple times without having a nested structure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way for me to do a nested ng-repeat call, but not having it create a nested structure.

I.e.

Say I have this in my script:

```
$scope.animals = {
      dog : {
        rupert: {
          size: 'big'
        }
      },
       cat : {
        jon: {
          size: 'small'
        },
        don: {
          size: 'small'
        }
      },
       pig : {
        mike: {
          size: 'big'
        }
      }
    }
```

and this in my html

```
<ul>
   <ul ng-repeat="(type,animal) in animals">
      <li ng-repeat="(name,description) in animal">
        <span>
          This is {{name}} the {{type}}, he is really {{description.size}}.
         </span>
       </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Here is a plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/BtAIejohzzVjrwWDfBWK?p=preview

Basically at the moment this creates something like this:

```
<ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>
                This is don the cat, he is really small.
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>
                This is jon the cat, he is really small.
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>
                This is rupert the dog, he is really big.
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>
                This is mike the pig, he is really big.
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I'd like it to make something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>
            This is don the cat, he is really small.
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            This is jon the cat, he is really small.
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            This is rupert the dog, he is really big.
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            This is mike the pig, he is really big.
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So is there a way to formulate this to get this result, do something of this sort **(this doesn't work lol)**

```
<ul>
    <ng-repeat="(type,animal) in animals">
        <li ng-repeat="(name,description) in animal">
            <span>
                This is {{name}} the {{type}}, he is really {{description.size}}.
            </span>
        </li>
    </ng-repeat>
</ul>
```

***note I'd like to avoid doing this**

```
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(name,description) in animals.dog">
            <span>
                This is {{name}} the dog, he is really {{description.size}}.
            </span>
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="(name,description) in animals.cat">
            <span>
                This is {{name}} the cat, he is really {{description.size}}.
            </span>
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="(name,description) in animals.pig">
            <span>
                This is {{name}} the pig, he is really {{description.size}}.
            </span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably create a couple of dummy [ng-repeat-start/ng-repeat-end](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points) directives for the top level repeater.

```
 <ul>
    <!-- Remove it with an ng-if -->
    <li ng-repeat-start="(type,animal) in animals" ng-if="0"></li>

    <!-- Or do -->
    <!-- <li ng-repeat-start="(type,animal) in animals" ng-if="::type<0"></li> -->

    <li ng-repeat="(name,description) in animal">
      <span>
        This is {{name}} the {{type}}, he is really {{description.size}}.
      </span>
    </li>

    <!-- Remove it with an ng-if -->
    <li ng-repeat-end  ng-if="0"></li>

    <!-- Or do -->
    <!-- <li ng-repeat-end  ng-if="::type<0"></li> -->
  </ul>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/87mFk7Nqbd25ATvOJcBZ?p=preview)**